# How to disable View mode in RStudio in Browse mode

Tags: r, debugging, ide, rstudio

Is there a way to disable the View mode in RStudio when debugging functions?
[image]

Code example:

```
myfun <- function() {
  browser()
}
myfun()
```

I am aware of the fact that it does not open for sourced functions, might be undesireable often since it might be unclear which function I debug etc.

Only question: is it possible or not. Was unsuccessfully searching in "Global Options"

Comment: You might want to raise an issue, the team is very responsive in my experience : https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues