# Debugging R Shiny with browser() statements less painfully

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to debug an R Shiny app using the browser() statement without it opening new tabs in RStudio during the debugging?

At the moment, when in browser mode, when running the code line by line, RStudio automatically opens a new tab with two dots in the tab name.  This is a huge time waster having to close the tab and then find the position of the cursor for each line being run manually in browser mode.

Is there a way to stop RStudio opening this new tab?

Comment: Using breakpoints is not an option?

Comment: Breakpoints only work in shinyServer function and I have the code split into modules, cf https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html.

Comment: I guess currently there is no option in RStudio to turn it off. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66301799/how-to-disable-view-mode-in-rstudio-in-browse-mode) had a bounty started a few weeks ago - no result.

Comment: This is a new "feature", it's not always been this way. I hope someone figures out how to turn this behavior off, it's extremely annoying.